# TFLearn Autoencoder allocates all memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I trying to build a simple Auto-Encoder with TF-Learn. The training images have a resolution of 150 by 150 pixels (and 3 channels) and I converted them with TFLearn in a h5df file. The problem is that the network immediately allocates all ~16 GB of free memory.

Here is my code:

```
h5_file = h5py.File(os.path.join(data_folder, 'dataset150-150.h5'), 'r')
X = h5_file['X']
Y = h5_file['X']

batch_size = 8

# Building the encoder
encoder = tflearn.input_data(shape=[batch_size, 150, 150, 3], name='input')
# Flatten the input layer
encoder = tflearn.reshape(encoder, new_shape=[batch_size, 67500])
encoder = tflearn.fully_connected(encoder, 67500)
encoder = tflearn.fully_connected(encoder, 512)
hidden = tflearn.fully_connected(encoder, 16)
decoder = tflearn.fully_connected(hidden, 512)
decoder = tflearn.fully_connected(decoder, 67500)
# Reshape the input layer to image shape
decoder = tf.reshape(decoder, [batch_size,150,150,3])

# Regression, with mean square error
net = tflearn.regression(decoder, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=0.001, loss='mean_square', metric=None)

# Training the auto encoder
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_verbose=3, tensorboard_dir="./AutoEncoder")
model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Maybe someone see my mistake? Thanks in advance.